# How to embed an dynamic svg in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, api, svg, maps

I'm trying to make something like this https://vanadhara-showcase-lite.azurewebsites.net/.

I am using Google JavaScript api attached an image but after creating highlighted hotspots from inkspace and then embedding the image in Google Maps. I'm not getting the same dynamic highlighted areas with interactions on click or hover, instead I'm only getting static image.

Comment: This [example](https://codepen.io/coder-karen/pen/mpPwNa) might help you, check it out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.